# I just pressed an shortcut and my Visual Studio code editor started to show a lot of "----"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I disable this?

The "-" in the red square:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can disable it in the main menu:

Edit > Advanced > View White Space